# Reverse latitude and longitude in mongodb 2Dsphere indexes

Tags: mongodb, google-maps, 2dsphere

Actually, mongodb stores coordinates ordered by `[<longitude>, <latitude>]`.

As I use directly db models in my angular app, and all services like google maps or openstreetmap uses the maritime format (reversed order), it would be really more easy to play with coordinates without having to reverse them always in my calls.

Is there a way to do that on version 3.0.4 ?

Thanks by advance if you have a solution !

Comment: When you query, do something like select latitude, longitude from table instead of select longitude, latitude from table.

Comment: My API is already used by third services and I don't want to break all stuff done.
My solution was to reverse each location before returning API response...